# Data deleted after crashing xamarin forms android app

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms

After crashing android app,my sqlite data deleted.
How to solve this?

Comment: What exactly is deleted? The whole database? Or just the changes you made?
When the app is closed properly, does it happen also?
How do you save your data? Do you use transactions?
Please provide the code you use.

Comment: Only database table data deleted,when app throw an exception then android app getting crash.while opening the app second time then no data found on my sqlite table.

Comment: Does the table had any values before crashing?? What is the Exception causing?

Answer (score 0):

I can't see your code, so I'll try to guess. 
You probably don't use transactions in your code. So your changes, while being visible to your connection, are not actually committed until you close the connection to the database. If you close the connection only when your app is closed, than the changes are never committed in the case of app crash.
The solution is to commit the changes immediately by wrapping them inside

```
your_db.RunInTransaction
```